# How to make used index unavailable to replace

Tags: java

I'm currently making an array program and I want to know how can I make an index number not be able to use again. For example, if I used to put a value at index[3], I wont be able to use index[3] and replace the value inside it but I can access it.

Comment: It is a little bit confusing, can you provide an example? You mean once you set a value to a position in array (e.g. index[3]), you want to be able to access it but not modify it?

Comment: does 'not be able to use again' mean you want to detect which indexes you have already used so your program will choose another index?

Comment: You could keep used indices in a set. Then if the user tried to assign an index that is already in that set, you could handle it however you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize the whole array to some undefined value e.g. -1.Before putting value at that index,check if it is -1,then only put else don't put.And if you need to store every possible value in the array then the only way to solve this is declare another boolean array of same size and initialize it to false.And once you put value at index i in your array then mark boolean_array[i] =true.And before putting any value check if the boolean_array[i] is false.If it is true then that index is already used.

Comment: won't work if you need to store every possible value.

Comment: Edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't, what you try to do is make an index "final", but you can't. 
You can only set the whole array final but it won't give you the restriction you want.

If you want to achieve that, you'll need to use a wrapper and don't directly use the array.

For example,

```
myArrayWraper.add("toto",3)
```

You create a class `MyArrayWraper`containing an array and you implement a method `add` that will check if the index is already used.